# Asp.net devexpress : getting the datasource of the aspxgridview back to collection

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am very new to dev express .

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="aspxgvOMContracts" runat="server" KeyFieldName="OMContractId" Settings-UseFixedTableLayout="true"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" Settings-HorizontalScrollBarMode="Auto" Width="477px" Theme="PlasticBlue" 
                                OnRowUpdating="aspxgvOMContracts_OnRowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="aspxgvOMContracts_OnRowUpdated">
                                <SettingsPager PageSize="5" />
                                <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="true" />
                                <SettingsEditing Mode="Inline" />
                          <%--      <Styles>
                                    <CommandColumnItem Spacing="">
                                        <Paddings PaddingLeft="7" PaddingRight="7" />
                                    </CommandColumnItem>
                                </Styles>--%>
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ButtonType="Image" Width="65px" VisibleIndex="0">
                                        <EditButton Visible="True" Image-Url="../Content/Images/icon_edit.png">
                                        </EditButton>
                                        <UpdateButton Visible="True" Image-Url="../Content/Images/icon_update.png">
                                        </UpdateButton>
                                        <CancelButton Visible="true" Image-Url="../Content/Images/icon_cancel.png">
                                        </CancelButton>
                                        <DeleteButton Visible="true" Image-Url="../Content/Images/icon_delete.png">
                                        </DeleteButton>
                                        <ClearFilterButton Visible="True">
                                        </ClearFilterButton>
                                        <%--  <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="headerLabel" runat="server">
                                            </dx:ASPxLabel>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>--%>
                                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="OrganisationName" Caption="OrganisationName" VisibleIndex="1">
                                        <PropertiesComboBox TextField="CompanyName" ValueField="OrganisationId" ValueType="System.Int32">
                                        </PropertiesComboBox>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTimeEditColumn FieldName="DateAnnounced" Caption="DateAnnounced" VisibleIndex="2">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTimeEditColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Cost" Caption="Cost" VisibleIndex="3">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CostCurrency" Caption="Cost Currency" VisibleIndex="4">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                </Columns>

                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

and in code behind i Bind the data as

```
aspxgvOMContracts.DataSource = phase.OMContracts;
        aspxgvOMContracts.DataBind();
```

here phase.OMContracts is of type List()

Now once I edit any row I need the modified collection back . How do I get the modified collection ?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the DataSource Property of AspxGridview control then you can directly access that assigned assigned `List` from DataSource Property, it is a read and write property.

Check the documentation:

[ASPxDataWebControlBase.DataSource Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesASPxDataWebControlBase_DataSourcetopic)

> Gets or sets the object from which the data-bound control retrieves
>   its list of data items.

From: [Get GridView data source to Data table](http://forums.asp.net/t/1783073.aspx/1)

if you bind gridview on every postback..then you can get DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

Same for you alos as `List<SomeType> data = grid.DataSource as List<SomeType>;`

Hope this help..